# MySQL selection of number quoted or not

Tags: mysql, select, quotes

What's the correct way to write MySQL select query e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM table users WHERE status = 1 AND salary = 2000.00
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM table users WHERE status = '1' AND salary = '2000.00'
```

1. Should it have quotes when I reference numbers integer or decimal?
2. What this quote character ` they use in phpMyAdmin is it has some special purpose or its just cosmetic thing?

Answer (score 1):

1. If the column is an INTEGER, you do not have to put quotes around integers. MySQL understands this. However, it **doesn't really matter if you do**: MySQL can automatically convert between datatypes, and the extra cost for one such conversion is negligible. (unlike for example when joining two tables on a column with a different datatype, where the conversion needs to be done for millions of rows - that is expensive).
2. phpMyAdmin puts backticks ` around the schema/table/column names to avoid confusion. For example, a table called `my.table` needs these backticks to be accessible, else MySQL doesn't know if `my` is the schema and `table` is the table name.

   For this exact reason `my.table` would be an unwise choice for a table name - someone somewhere is bound to make a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the data type of `salary`. If it's stored like it should be, then without quotes is fine.

Otherwise (bad design or whatever) the quotes are necessary to avoid implicit casts (which are bad).

Answer (score 0):

If the data type of the column is char or varchar then you should use quotes to make MySQL understand that it is character type. For integer, numbers there is no need to use quotes. If salary is of type number then quotes are not necessary.

Answer (score -1):

You only need quotes when the value is not a number, so for strings, dates, etc you enquote.

And phpmyadmin adds backticks so that users like my mom add them all the time to bug me